# Getting 'HTTP 502.5 Process Failure' from time to time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have self-contained application targeting .net 4.6.1 running on IIS 8.

From time to time we get the famous error `HTTP 502.5 Process Failure` and a couple of same logs in the Event Viewer with `Failed to start process with commandline '".\<appname>.exe" ', ErrorCode = '0x80070002`.

I have read and tried every post on the internet about that error and still have no idea why this happens.

Today I just restarted the IIS (after I added some binding) and when I opened the website I got it, after less then a minute everything was fine and couldn't reproduce it.

**Additional info:**

1. My web.config looks like:

`<aspNetCore processPath=".\<app_name>.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />`

2. Found some warnings in the Event Viewer with the `Maximum rapid fail count per minute of '10' exceeded.` - no idea if this is related.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to reproduce this on our pre-prod environment. After I restart the IIS and try to open http://localhost I got the error from above - EVERY TIME. As soon as I hit the Application on http://localhost/ everything is working.

Comment: Did you tried replacing `<app_name>` with actual application name exe?

Comment: this is a placeholder I put just to hide the name of my application :)

Comment: @DilyanDimitrov what do you see in the stdout logs?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan nothing, it is empty, I think the error happens when dotnet core module tries to start.

Comment: Do you have the adapt core handler installed ... you say this is intermittent so I assume you do but just confirming ...

Comment: What is 'adapt core handler' ?

Comment: I meant aspnetcore module for IIS, Damn! auto correct

Comment: Yeah, it is there, you can see the update, I made some workaround with URL rewriting, but still, it is quite strange

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Techy yes, let's see if I can remember everything back then. I had some redirects on the IIS, which redirected to the HTTPS and to the ApplicationName. After each restart of IIS if I hit the URL for the website (through the domain name), the redirects get fired and somehow the AspNet Module wasn't initialized and started but the url was pointing to the application with that error displaying. If I browse the website internally with localhost the AspNet Module was starting up and everything was working from that time on.